# How to avoid `WriteableBitmap buffer size is not sufficient` exception for Bgr24 format?

Tags: wpf, bitmap, writeablebitmap

I want to create a `WriteableBitmap` and then set it as an `Image.Source`. I am interested only in **RGB**, with full opacity, so I chose the `Bgr24` format.

Now when I am trying to write some pixels to the bitmap, using `WritePixels()` I get the *Buffer size is not sufficient* exception.

```cs
 wb = new WriteableBitmap(255, 255, 96d, 96d, PixelFormats.Bgr24, null);

            for (int x = 0; x < wb.PixelWidth; x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < wb.PixelHeight; y++)
                {
                    byte blue = GetBlue();
                    byte green = GetGreen();
                    byte red = GetRed();
                    byte[] pixelColor = { blue, green, red };

                    // position where the pixel will be drawn
                    Int32Rect rect = new Int32Rect(x, y, 1, 1);
                    int stride = wb.PixelWidth * wb.Format.BitsPerPixel / 8;

                    // Write the pixel.
                    wb.WritePixels(rect, pixelColor, stride, x);
                }
            }
```

Here is my question, isn't `pixelColor` size (3 bytes) good enough for that operation?

### Edit

It works only if I initialize the `WriteableBitmap` as with `width` and `height` of 1.

```
 wb = new WriteableBitmap(255, 255, 96d, 96d, PixelFormats.Bgr24, null);
```

Is `rect`s size the problem?

Comment: Isn't the stride the number of bytes in a line @Andy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have wrongly used `x` as input buffer offset, which should be zero:

```
wb.WritePixels(rect, pixelColor, stride, 0);
```

You may also use `x` and `y` directly as destination values, with an appropriate source rect and stride, like

```
wb.WritePixels(new Int32Rect(0, 0, 1, 1), pixelColor, 3, x, y);
```